# Find new camera matrix from two set of input points with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Consider the following input data as given:

- `CP`: camera intrinsic parameter (3x3) ([more info](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/))
- `WP`: 4x 3D world coordinates (ie. 4 points in world space)

Now consider the following variables:

- `CM1`: current camera location & rotation (4x4 matrix)
- `SP1`: 4x 2D screen coordinates (ie. 4 points in screen space)
- `SP2`: again 4x 2D screen coordinates (ie. 4 points in screen space)

with the constraint that `SP1` is derived from looking through the camera at `CM1` with camera parameters `CP` at `WP`. For clarity, let's express that relationship as the following (although this might not be correct formula in matrix maths).

```
SP1 = CM1 * CP * WP
```

I am trying to find the new camera location & rotation `CM2` such that

```
SP2 = CM2 * CP * WP
```

---

I've been trying to use `cvCalibrateCamera()` but haven't been successful. I'm glad that I finally figured out how to convert all the data so that the function no longer spits out an error. But now I think that the function might not be the correct one to use in this case, as I have no idea how to apply the output data. (I have the feeling that the function is used to compute camera intrinsic parameters from input data, but the documentation is not clear to me. In case you are interested in my humble attempt: http://pastebin.com/WC8CKUhZ)

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to compute with openCV? I couldn't find any function that would match my requirements more than `cvCalibrateCamera()` (guessed from the data I can feed into it).

Comment: To understand more your problem, you want to estimate the camera pose given four 2D image points? If for each 2D image points you have the corresponding 3D coordinates, you can use [cv::solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d). You calibrate your camera once, the intrinsic parameters are valid as long as you don't modify your camera (change the lens for example). The formula should be: SP1 = CP * CM1 * WP and SP2 = CP * CM2 * WP.

Comment: @Catree Not exactly. What I do have is the objects points, image points, camera parameters **and** camera pose from one "recording". Now the object points stay the same, but the image points change, and I want to find the new camera pose so that the image points match with the object points again (after projecting the object points to the image plane through the to-be-found camera pose). I am not sure how to use `solvePnP()` for this. :(

Comment: The function `cv::solvePnP` estimates the camera pose (the translation + the rotation) using the 3D object points and the corresponding 2D image points + the camera parameters. It is more or less one of the methods used in the calibration process: estimate the extrinsic + intrinsic parameters using know 3D object points (the chessboard pattern) and 2D image points (found by image processing). No more information are needed with a small exception: some methods can used an initial camera pose guess for better accuracy or as an initialization for the pose estimation problem.